# How to I interpret these htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite

I was given a set or re-write rules for a new website.  I've never used them before and I'm trying to understand what we are doing here

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.myco\.com  
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.myco.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(CCSFG|images|fonts|themes|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

If I understand this, the first ruleset

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.myco\.com  
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.myco.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

says:
If HTTP_HOST is anything AND
if HTTP_HOST doesn't start with www.myco.com
then
rewrite any page request to start with http://www.myco.com/, return a 301 redirect and stop processing more rules

The next ruleset

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(CCSFG|images|fonts|ee-system|themes|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

says:
If the request doesn't start with CCSFG,image or fonts or, etc (non-case sensitive)
then
rewrite the whole request to prepend /index.php/ and stop processing more rules

Is my interpretation correct?

If so, what would be the purpose of the second ruleset?  Why would I want to prepend /index.php/ to these entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, pretty much exactly.

The first `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .` exists so as to not redirect loop someone who isn't sending a host header - it's verifying that the host header variable contains at least one character.

The prepending behavior exists to force page requests to be handled by `index.php`, likely for pretty URLs - the exceptions are for locations that need to be served by a physically present file.

So, for `/images/image2.jpg`, it's letting Apache serve the file at that location, but for `/contentpage/1/2/3` it's rewriting to `/index.php/contentpage/1/2/3`, letting the PHP app do its thing.

Actually, it's technically rewriting to `//index.php/contentpage/1/2/3`; it's clear that it has a changed base (from being in an htaccess file), and it's not taking that into account for its destination.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Are you suggesting the leading / may be superfluous

Comment: Yup - it's not hurting anything, but it doesn't need to be there.

Comment: One more question - what does the $1 represent in the last RewriteCond line? Is it the request?  is $1 always the request?

Comment: It's the match in the below `RewriteRule`, the `(.*)`.

Comment: Really, so the conditions & rules are interpreted as a sort of unit?  Curious.

Comment: Yeah - the conditions are evaluated alongside the rule that they apply to, and you can use matches from one directive in the other.